# In a double-linked list the pointers instead of storing the address of each other they are pointing at same location

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I want to create a double-linked list so when I am adding a new node "tmp"

i.e.

```
*q , *tmp ;    
q->next = tmp;    
tmp->prev = q;
```

but the result I am getting is more like:

```
 tmp = q;
```

Please help.

Comment: It might help if you showed some code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting in the middle of the list, you will have to update q's old next.

```
*q, *tmp, *n;
n=q->next;
q->next=tmp;
tmp->next=n;
tmp->prev=q;
n->prev=tmp;
```

Comment: thanks! i got it but now i have a different problem -  the linked linked is not taking more then 86 elements, in doing so the program gets hanged and after sometime the output shows  "killed".                                                                                                       here is what i have written to add a new node

Comment: here is what i have written to add a new     node                                                                                                                    s = start;
       while(s != NULL)
      {
       if(s->next == NULL)
    {s->next = tmp; //(tmp is the new node)                                                       
      tmp->prev = s; break;                                                     
    }
       else 
    ns = ns->next;
      }

Comment: @ShashankJyotiYadav I have no idea what is happening in your situation, but it sounds like a memory problem. Maybe your environment can't take that many nodes?